# How is Azure Data out computed?

Tags: azure

I'm on a free trial of Windows Azure at the moment. 
All I've done is deploy a standard MVC start up template, "My MVC Application", to the service.

However when reading the data out charges (zerod costed out while I'm on a trial account) I see

> 01/10/2011  Windows Azure Platform - All Services   Zone 2  Data
>   Transfer Out (GB)  11.414393  Southeast Asia  Compute

That's 11GB! 
The page is all of 3Kb and I'm the only one who knows it exists so how on earth does the useage get that high. I tried calling MS Support but they offered no explaination and if I were not on the intro package I would be billed for this amount.

Has anyone any ideas on where 11GB went for a 3Kb MVC template? 
Note: I have no corresponding usage from my ISP bandwidth so it's "cant" have been me.

UPDATE:

The usage was never explained. Microsoft talked to itself but ultimately was unable to offer any explaination for the useage spike. I have not since experienced a similar problem. I dont believe Microsoft would intentionally rip us off as that would be a short term gain that would ultimately backfire but in terms of an error they apparently have no means to drill into the figures they bill you for in any meaningful way.

So i think the lesson is that **you must implement your own metrics on this service to cross check the figures for which you will be billed**.

Comment: O.k. Ive taken a deep breath and call MS services yet again. I got through to the US and they have a said they will have their data analysis team investigate Might take a couple of days though. I cant say i like the feeling of this at all though. When it's 11GB it's a stand out error of some sort. But what about when it's a sneaky 100MB here and a sneaky 200MB there. The billing process needs to be much more transparent and integrous IMHO. We should be able to drill down into that summary figure and see where the bits went.

Comment: Did you get the answer? I've faced the same issue in my Azure cloud service.

Comment: @AndreiSchneider Foir me the answer was as per the update. Implement my own metrics and compare. Since this was after the fact I never found out why this occured as per post. But I haven't had any major scares since and Im now a paying customer.... The dashboards in the management panel are also a great deal more informative.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable Content Delivery Network (CDN) ? The mechanism will transfer your data to other service zone. But still, 11GB is extremely large compared with your actual content size.

See more details at: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/faq/

Comment: No I didn't. I was going to load in some high density images for testing how well the cdn worked. But at this rate it'd blow right out so until i know what has happened i wont be doing anything. This is where cloud gets spookey IMO. How do you know the charge is real?

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you've hit the page 4000 times?

Data transfer is computed by counting how many bytes leave our data center (from your app, storage account, service bus, caching, etc.). If you're not using anything other than compute (just hosting this app), it would mean that 11GB of data were served up by IIS in your web role.

Comment: No I have alife. LOL. But a couple of times i have logged into the management portal and I cant get to hosted services, it just keeps on cycling on a 30 sec refresh. So if that's doing that then potentially some other "service" is cycling the default page of this template.

Comment: I should also add the obvious. That if it were in some way "Me" I'd have a corresponding usage with my ISP and that's not the case.

Comment: Response heads can all add up too. For example, these are currently some of the headers served from my Azure website instance:

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5  
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13  
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5  
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Were you launching background threads that connected to web systems outside of Azure? I just saw something on my own Azure Website that made me think that some abandoned HttpClient requests launched with await were running all night long. (I must go on a bug hunt.) Even though my browser wasn't waiting for the requests, it looks like Azure counts data that was intended for delivery. This suggests the metering isn't done at the network level, but somewhere in IIS. Data needn't make it to the wire, just some output buffer.